# HTML POST response

Tags: php, html, post

I have a PHP script invoked as part of POST which returns Boolean true/false based on user information. 
Couple of questions:
1) What is the HTTP header when the PHP return construct is used ?
2) Is there any way to capture this POST response value or do I need to return a JSON array as some examples have suggested ?

Regards
Melanie.

PS: I am fairly newbie to PHP, so if this question has already been tackled, please just point out the links.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the HTTP header when the PHP return construct is used ?

`return`ing ends a function and returns a value to whatever called it.

It doesn't change the HTTP headers, or HTTP response body, at all (unless whatever the value is returned to modifies them using it).

> Is there any way to capture this POST response value

How you read an HTTP response depends on what you did to make the request in the first place

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin said, it depends on how the script is being used. If it's the target of an HTML form, the browser expects the output to be a web page to display, so you should output HTML. If it's being used by an AJAX client, the output should normally be JSON -- you can use the `json_encode` function to produce this.